# How to reference a SO question statically

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, deleted-questions, 10k-tools

Very often on Meta somebody asks a question like "should I delete this?" or "what is this user doing?". Unfortunately, when the question actually is deleted or the user banned, we lose the original reference for future consultation. Here's what I suggest:

Instead of linking to example questions, either:

1. Quote them,
2. Screenshot (& imgur) them (what I personally do), or
3. Artificially preserve them as an example.

Comment: It's quite annoying. 10k (rep to see deleted posts) is a big number.

Comment: @bjb568 What do you mean?

Comment: At 10k reputation you can view deleted posts.

Comment: @connor I see. But certainly ordinary users would benefit from seeing those examples, right?

Comment: I completely agree. I don't have 10k either and it's frustrating to read a meta question that links to a deleted post.

Answer (score 13):

The link to questions (almost) always points to the question, since all deletions are soft deletions.  Very rarely is something ever hard deleted.

It's just that often **you** don't have privileges to see the question as the privilege to see deleted content is only for the OP, moderators, and 10K users.  So to answer the unasked part of your question, you should still always link to the post in question because there are a number of people who can see it.

However, beyond that, if you feel the particular text of the question is extremely relevant to answering the question, then you should also quote the post.  An image would be the 2nd choice for cases when a text version does not help.

The reason why I think quoting is a better option is mostly personal preference for readability, as well as for availability.

- Images may capture more information, but are extremely difficult to read in many cases.  Ultimately it really depends on the message that is trying to be conveyed in the meta question.
- Some corporate firewalls lock anything coming from imgr.com so those users will be left completely in the dark.

Is the text more important or the overall picture of everything going on in the post.  If the content of the post is the only thing relevant (which it usually is), then I think making it easier for everyone to read is the driving factor.

But in general, unless the content of the post is necessary to answer the question or provide the appropriate context for future users, then a link is all that should be needed.  Simple curiosity as to what prompted the meta question isn't usually enough to warrant going the extra distance to preserve the question's content for all users

Comment: I know that I can't see deleted content. But for matters such as question relevance or editing ethics, isn't it imperative that all users see the example? Yes, I agree that linking is helpful --- maybe an image link to kill two birds with one stone. Do you have a reason for quoting (by which I assume that you mean copy-pasting _code_) as opposed to imaging?

Comment: @SimonKuang In the majority of cases, a meta question that links to a deleted question can still be answered, or have meaningful answers, without seeing the deleted questions.  In rare exceptional cases, yes, you really can't understand the question without seeing the deleted post, but usually you don't need to.

Comment: @SimonKuang I've explained why I think quoting is the better option.

Comment: it is probably worth noting that images are blocked for some readers (I recall complaints about corporate firewalls blocking imgur and making it harder to read posts because of that)

Comment: @gnat excellent point - in fact my company's firewall blocks imgr, so I deal with this regularly.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, posters are expected to apply rules laid out in [How To Answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) guidance:

> #### Provide context for links
>
> ...add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

These rules are the same at meta and main site.

The only difference is that violations at meta typically have less painful consequences compared to these at main site: there are lots of 10K users and moderators actively reading and editing content and able to recover it in case if linked post is deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting idea for those of us whose reputation is under 10K, when deleted posts can be seen.  At this point, I would think they're still at the early stage of this Meta and want to encourage people to use the site.  Still, what you're proposing should be encouraged as a legitimate edit to a question, just as formatting code in `this way` is encouraged as a legitimate edit on Stack Overflow.

Screenshots should serve the purpose.  One problem of quotes is that other Users might reference other parts of the questions and answers, which have not been quoted.  For example, a quote may miss an essential component elsewhere in a question.